# How to horizontally align a button in a panel with dynamic size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jxTUw/7/) is my jsFiddle simple case as a starter for you.

I want the `create` button stay in the center of the west pane as my drag the resize bar.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Center the text on the parent element:

```
.ui-layout-west {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jxTUw/8/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Another question, If I have two buttons and only want one of them to be centered, how can I do that? Thank you.